# Replace comma to pipe in VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I have CSV where the I am replacing `,` (comma) to `|` ( pipe) and I'm trying to run the below code and it's giving me the run time error.

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject ("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim filetxt
Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8
Const fmtUnicode = -1, fmtASCII = 0, fmtDefault = -2
Set re = New RegExp
Dim strInput
Dim Matches
Dim Match
Dim myFile
myFile = "\\xxxx\yyyy\Cxxxxx\Business Performance Reporting\H.csv"
re.IgnoreCase = True
Set filetxt = objFSO.OpenTextFile(myFile, ForReading, False, fmtDefault)
Dim arrFileLines()
i = 0
Do Until filetxt.AtEndOfStream
  ReDim Preserve arrFileLines(i)
  arrFileLines(i) = filetxt.ReadLine
  strInput = arrFileLines(i)
  'WScript.Echo(strInput)
  re.Pattern = "\s"
  re.Global = True
  arrFileLines(i) = re.Replace(strInput, ",", "|")
  i = i + 1
Loop
filetxt.Close
Set filetxt = objFSO.OpenTextFile(myFile, ForWriting, False, fmtDefault)
For j = LBound(arrFileLines) To UBound(arrFileLines)
  filetxt.WriteLine(arrFileLines(j))
Next
filetxt.Close
Set filetxt = Nothing
```

Comment: How many more of these questions does there need to be??...take your pick from [umpteen duplicates](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com&oq=site%3Astackoverflow.com&q=+#safe=off&q=site:stackoverflow.com+vbscript+replace+string)!

Answer (score 1):

`re.Pattern = "\s"` means you are looking for white space? I don't think that is relevant here.

```
arrFileLines(i) = re.Replace(strInput, ",", "|")
```

The [`Replace()` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9z80300(v=vs.84).aspx) of a `RegExp` object in VBScript only takes 2 parameters.

Depending on the exact data format in your CSV file (e.g. whether you have something with comma included in a quoted string), instead of using a regular expression you may just use the VBScript [`Replace()` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/238kz954(v=vs.84).aspx).

A simple `arrFileLines(i) = Replace(strInput, ",", "|")` will do the job. Remove `set re = New RegExp` and all the other `re.??` from your code.

Comment: Hi Ansgar Wiechers, thanks for the help :) but seems that all columns at the end is getting substituted however I will have a look into it. However I have a csv which have firstname, lastname ( single column having comma in between). The tools which I am using SSIS or TD utilities thinking it as a seperate columns ..so thought of solution to substitute only those commas ...